# Sending an Array in an HTTP POST

Tags: c#, arrays, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to send an array as a JSON string in the request body using HTTP POST:

```
{
    {
      A: 0,
      B: 1
    },
    {
      A: 2,
      B: 3
    }
}
```

I have the following data structure:

```
public class Test
    {        
        [Display(Name = "A")]
        [Range(1, 2147483647)]
        [Required]        
        public int A { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "B")]
        [Range(0, 2147483647)]
        [Required]
        public int B { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(WriteResponse))]
        [Route("Account/{clientId:int}/Test")]
        public IHttpActionResult PostEventTest(int clientId, [FromBody]Test[] test){}
```

When I hit this action, the test param is null. 
How can I receive an array of a certain type through the request body?

Comment: 1) your json is not an array 2) It is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Test should represent the whole JSON, then it is wrong. Even your complete JSON is wrong, because it is not an array. Correct JSON would be:

```
{
    "list": [
      {
          "A": "0",
          "B": "1"
      },
      {
          "A": "2",
          "B": "3"
      }
    ]
}
```

Or something like this:

```
{
    "item1": {
      A: 0,
      B: 1
    },
    "Item2": {
      A: 2,
      B: 3
    }
}
```

For this, you model has to change to. For the first example your model should look like:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public IList<Test> list
    { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{        
        [Display(Name = "A")]
        [Range(1, 2147483647)]
        [Required]        
        public int A { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "B")]
        [Range(0, 2147483647)]
        [Required]
        public int B { get; set; }
}
```

For the second example the `Test` class would be the same, only `TestModel` would change:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public Test item1
    { get; set; }

    public Test item2
    { get; set; }
}
```

But only the first example is an array. To test whether your JSON is correct, use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

**EDIT**

With my example, you don't need the `[FromBody]` part, because you can pass `TestModel` as a parameter of your method. Which is in my point of view even nicer.

Comment: what if you don't know before hand how many items will be in the json?

Comment: Than use my first example. In the web controller you will get an instance of the `IList<Test>` with all models in it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are sending is not an array. It should go something like:

```
{"test":[
    {"A":"0", "B":"0"}, 
    {"A":"0", "B":"1"}, 
    {"A":"1","B":"1"}
]}
```

See more [here (w3schools).](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)